# 0 rows returned, why?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, wildcard

Can anyone help me understand why I get 0 rows returned?  The following is my query:

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, s.studentprogram
 FROM student s
  WHERE s.studentprogram =
  (SELECT p.ProfessorProgram 
     FROM professor p 
       WHERE p.ProfessorProgram LIKE 'C_');
```

The question reads: Create a query/subquery to display student first name, last name and program. The program must be same as that in the professor table and the professor’s program starts with a ‘C’. This query will use a subquery and not a join.

Table: **student**

Column: studentno, studentprogram, phoneno, age, firstname, lastname

Table: **professor**

Column: ProfessorId, ProfessorProgram, PhoneNo, Age, ProfessorName

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
WHERE p.ProfessorProgram LIKE 'C_'
```

Is checking both that `ProfessorProgram` starts with a `'C'` and that it has exactly two characters.

The question probably intends:

```
WHERE p.ProfessorProgram LIKE 'C%'
```

I don't know if that is what the question *really* wants.  Because you can just check the student's program.  And a "program code" seems like an odd way to link the two tables.  However, if these are the only two tables, then that is about the only choice.

Comment: I will have to clarify with the professor.  I switched the 'C_' to 'C%' but it returned with Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @SteveWong . . . Use `IN` instead of `=`.

Comment: returns with 0 rows, is the issue with my "WHERE s.studentprogram"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a query like this :

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, s.studentprogram
 FROM student s
  WHERE s.studentprogram IN
  (SELECT p.ProfessorProgram 
     FROM professor p 
       WHERE p.ProfessorProgram LIKE 'C%');
```

As I see your comments on the first answer by Gordan, if having `=` is resulting into error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`  then using IN should not be returning you 0 rows. If it's still happening would you mind sharing the data you have inside tables? This could only happen if the ProfessorProgram starting with `C` has no associated students with it.

Hope we are making our point clear and getting your question right.

Comment: ah, it was such a small little fix! Thanks for the help

Comment: Happy to help! Could you please mark the helpful comment as answer so that it could help others facing same issue in future? Thanks!